# Why is GeoHistogram messing with the Bins?

Tags: geographics, entity

Consider some precise location data as follows:

```
plotData={{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"California","UnitedStates"}],3},{Entity["City",{"SantaClara","California","UnitedStates"}],2},{Entity["City",{"Chicago","Illinois","UnitedStates"}],2},{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"SanBenitoCounty","California","UnitedStates"}],2},{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Illinois","UnitedStates"}],2},{Entity["City",{"Tempe","Arizona","UnitedStates"}],1},{Entity["City",{"Seattle","Washington","UnitedStates"}],1},{Entity["City",{"Orange","California","UnitedStates"}],1},{Entity["City",{"LosAngeles","California","UnitedStates"}],1},{Entity["City",{"Boston","Massachusetts","UnitedStates"}],1},{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Washington","UnitedStates"}],1},{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Arizona","UnitedStates"}],1}};
```

As you can see the data is Geo Entities at various levels: `City`, `AdministrativeDivision` and `County` but for this example all within the US.

Since I have explicit frequencies, I have to convert to `WeightedData` as follows:

```
plotData=WeightedData@@Transpose@plotData
```

If I draw histogram without polygons then I get, all 18 frequencies:

```
GeoHistogram[plotData,ImageSize->Full]
```

If I plot them at `"Country"` bin I get 17 frequencies rather than 18:

```
GeoHistogram[plotData,"Country",ImageSize->Full]
```

If I try `"AdministrativeDivision"` then I get 1 frequency on the map:

```
GeoHistogram[plotData,"AdministrativeDivision",ImageSize->Full]
```

If I try a specific administrative division for the US's state system then I get 17 on map:

```
GeoHistogram[plotData,"USState",ImageSize->Full]
```

If I try a more specific subdivision of administrative division of US then I get all 18:

```
GeoHistogram[plotData,"USCounty",ImageSize->Full]
```

If I try even more specific city then I get 9 which is ok since reducing `"AdministrativeDivision"` to `"City"` is not possible and currently, there are 9 frequencies for `"City"` level data.

```
GeoHistogram[plotData,"City",ImageSize->Full]
```

I summarize the result:

> Automatic: 18
>
> "Country": 17 [Incorrect]
>
> "AdministrativeDivision": 1 [Incorrect]
>
> "USState": 17 [Incorrect]
>
> "USCounty": 18
>
> "City": 9

Now I apply some "AdministrativeDivision" level grouping on the data to get the following grouped data:

```
plotData={{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"California","UnitedStates"}],9},{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Illinois","UnitedStates"}],4},{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Washington","UnitedStates"}],2},{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Arizona","UnitedStates"}],2},{Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Massachusetts","UnitedStates"}],1}};
```

Again converting to `WeightedData`:

```
plotData=WeightedData@@Transpose@plotData
```

Now again applying the same bins for GeoHistogram in succession, I get the following:

> Automatic: 18
>
> "Country": 18
>
> "AdministrativeDivision": 0 [Incorrect]
>
> "USState": 18
>
> "USCounty": 18
>
> "City": 1 [Incorrect, city is not known in this grouped data]

Can somebody explain why am I getting incorrect frequencies for different bins? Is this a bug?

Also does anyone know how to get the list of cities in a particular `AdministrativeDivision`?

So how do I get all the cities in `Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Massachusetts","UnitedStates"}]` for example?

---

I know I can get all the `"Subdivisions"` (County in the case of US) or the `"CapitalCity"` by:

```
Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Massachusetts","UnitedStates"}]["Subdivisions"]
Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Massachusetts","UnitedStates"}]["CapitalCity"]
```

Then for each county, I can get its `"CapitalCity"` by:

```
Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"MiddlesexCounty","Massachusetts","UnitedStates"}]["CapitalCity"]
```

Similarly, I can move back up from "City" to "County" or major "AdministrativeDivision" by:

```
Entity["City",{"Cambridge","Massachusetts","UnitedStates"}]["County"]
Entity["City",{"Cambridge","Massachusetts","UnitedStates"}]["AdministrativeDivision"]
```